# Which way of representing a primitive class constant is better using ByteBuddy?

Tags: byte-buddy

ByteBuddy offers two mechanisms for representing a constant of a `Class` that is primitive:

- [`JavaConstant.Dynamic.ofPrimitiveType(Class)`](https://javadoc.io/static/net.bytebuddy/byte-buddy/1.10.17/net/bytebuddy/utility/JavaConstant.Dynamic.html#ofPrimitiveType-java.lang.Class-)
- [`TypeDescription.ForLoadedType.of(Class)`](https://javadoc.io/static/net.bytebuddy/byte-buddy/1.10.17/net/bytebuddy/description/type/TypeDescription.ForLoadedType.html#of-java.lang.Class-)

I am aware that the first one creates a "true" dynamic constant in the constant pool.  I am aware that the second is specially recognized by ByteBuddy and ultimately results in some other path to storing some sort of class constant in the constant pool.  (For example, you can see in the documentation of [`FixedValue#value(TypeDescription)`](https://javadoc.io/static/net.bytebuddy/byte-buddy/1.10.17/net/bytebuddy/implementation/FixedValue.html#value-net.bytebuddy.description.type.TypeDescription-) that a `TypeDescription` will end up being transformed into a constant in the constant pool in some unspecified non-ByteBuddy-specific format that (presumably) is not the same as a dynamic constant.)

I am also aware that ByteBuddy supports JVMs back to 1.5 and that only JDKs of version 11 or greater support true dynamic constants.  I am using JDK 15 and personally don't need to worry about anything earlier than that.

Given all this: Should I make constants-representing-primitive-classes using `JavaConstant.Dynamic.ofPrimitiveType(Class)`, or should I make them using `TypeDescription.ForLoadedType.of(Class)`?  Is there some advantage I'm missing to one representation or the other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dynamic constants are bootstrapt what causes a minimal runtime overhead. The static constants are therefore likely a better choice but it simplifies your code, there's no danger in using the dynamic ones.

Comment: Thanks. I understand you probably did `JavaConstant.Dynamic.ofPrimitiveType()` because it appears in `ConstantBootstraps` (https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/invoke/ConstantBootstraps.html#primitiveClass(java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles.Lookup,java.lang.String,java.lang.Class)). I wonder why it does?

Comment: Primitive constants are pseudo-constants in the JVM, they are represented as field accesses to [WRAPPER].TYPE, e.g. Boolean.TYPE for `boolean.class` where a field value cannot be an argument to a constantdynamic / invokedynamic bootstrap method. For being able to provide primitives, it is required to represent primitive types as true constants, in the understanding of the JVM.

Comment: Aha! Thank you; that also answers (finally for me) why those `TYPE` fields exist in the first place, given that you can always (in Java code) refer to, e.g., `int.class`.  Makes a certain kind of sense.